Replacing old smoke detectors - yellow interconnect is connected to a white wire
Replacing smoke detectors in our home and found that on the old Firex G-18 detectors that were connected, the yellow interconnect wire was hooked up to a separate white wire coming out of the electrical box. Can someone please explain what is going on here? I have to replace the harness as it's not compatible with the alarms I purchased so I have to figure out what the purpose of this single white wire is. Is it potentially the interconnect? Thank you.

how is everything connected in the box?

White wire that the interconnect is connected to appears to be on its own. Neutral and hot are doubled.

The white wire that the interconnect is connected to has a black wire with it that has been cut. The remaining white and black wires enter and exit the box at different locations. These wires are connected to the wiring harness. So including the white and black wires from the wiring harness, there are three white wires and three black wires in total all connected with the wire cap.

How the old harness was wired is moot if you are installing new detectors.  Wire the new units according to the provided instructions.

I'm trying to find out why the interconnect on the old harness was wired to a white wire.

If you test one station, do the others alarm or not? My suspicion is they will not. Whoever wired it up in the first place was an idiot.

@Doctamoneystacks can you take the detector base down and get us a clear shot looking into the back of the box please?

Nearly all hardwire detectors will have the same three wire interface. There should be a hot wire (black), a neutral (white), and a third wire (red or yellow) that is the interconnect. Interconnecting, btw, makes all of them alarm when one detects fire/smoke. The interconnect is a single wire, and relies on all of the interconnected units being on the same electrical circuit (breaker). Interconnecting detectors is required by code in many places, so you should definitely re-connect that when replacing.
From Firex install instructions:

Firex is a brand made by Kidde, so if your replacements are not all identical it's worth checking to see if they are electrically compatible. If that detector failed or is expired, I would consider replacing all of them since the others are likely to expire soon.
A two-conductor romex or BX cable may have been originally used out of convenience, even though only one conductor was needed. (It should be three-conductor romex with black/white/red, technically.) In that case, the black wire is likely unused and the black/white color coding has no real meaning.

Not related to the question, but that pictured Kidde Relay Module can be useful to provide a dry contact — one NC and one NO — that are activated when the alarm is activated.
